# What is the meaning of C# GetType() in the context of boxing?

Tags: .net, .net-4.6, gettype

`GetType()` is defined as `extern` in base Object.
As far as I  know, .NET source code (I use .NET 4.6) does not even 
provide the source code for any `extern` method. Does anybody know
where the source code for `GetType()` is?

I am trying to learn the boxing of simple types and I use `GetType()`
for various tests. Technically, when you run it on a literal/variable
of simple type then the literal/variable is automatically boxed
so what is the Type returned by `GetType()` supposed to represent? 
My tests show it is pre-boxed type which is problematic because
`GetType()` is run on a boxed type. Even if I cast a variable of 
simple type into an object first, and run `GetType()` on this object itself
then the returned Type still shows simple type. Also, if I declare
a variable of nullable simple type like int? and run `GetType()` on it
then Type.`IsValueType = True` and `Type.IsPrimitive = True`
(IsPrimitive should be false). Only when I check Type returned by
`typeof(int?)` I get `Type.IsValueType = True` and `Type.IsPrimitive = False`

Comment: What do you mean by 'pre-boxed type'? A unboxed and boxed value have the same type.

Comment: Yes, but when you have a variable `int? n = ...;`, then, because of the strange boxing behavior of the `Nullable<>` type, the call `n.GetType()` will not return the true type `typeof(int?)`. It will either blow up with an exception (when `HasValue` property is False), or return just `typeof(int)` (when `HasValue` is True).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're talking about here. `typeof(int?)` and `typeof(Nullable<int>)` resolve to the same type. `typeof(int?)` and `typeof(Nullable<>)` do not (one is open generic).

Comment: There are several issues here. First issue is the proper documentation of GetType(). After all you run it on an instance of an object and when it returns type that is not an object then we have a huge problem with basic logic. This is not a church where you follow a religion. You have to stick to a logic. Second issue is how to test a type during runtime.

Comment: "extern" just means that the method is implemented by the CLR.  Which is pretty common for such "works everywhere, does magic" methods, source is C++ and available through the CoreCLR project.  The returned type has the expected value, the framework does not have a dedicated type that means "boxed value".  It always provides you with the type of the value in the box.   Magic.  Nor do you need one, you already know because you are calling GetType() on a variable of type `object`.  If you have "doesn't work" code then you need to show it.

Comment: @rossipedia I agree with that. But boxing turns an `int?` into an `int` (in a box); or into a null reference (no box or other instance). When `n` has type `int?`, the call `n.GetType()` does not return `int?`.

Comment: You're right. That's pretty damn unexpected :-\